# I need a code that return true if all elemnts of a matrix is sorted from highest to lowest

Tags: java, matrix

I need a code that returns true if all elements of a matrix is sorted from highest to lowest By that i mean that if all elements of a matrix are in an decending order, like 3-2-1 it should return true if 3-1-2 it should return false. If the matrix is empty then it should return true. In any other scenario it should return false. Matrices are formed by this test.

```
@Test
    public void testSortedDescendantMatrixRows() {
        FirstSteps firstSteps = new FirstSteps();
        int[][] matrix1 = {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 4, 3}, {8, 7, 6}};
        assertTrue(firstSteps.isSortedDescendant(matrix1));
        int[][] matrix2 = {{3, 2, 2}, {5, 4, 3}, {8, 7, 6}};
        assertFalse(firstSteps.isSortedDescendant(matrix2));
        int[][] matrix3 = {{3, 2, 1}};
        assertTrue(firstSteps.isSortedDescendant(matrix3));
        int[][] matrix4 = {{}};
        assertTrue(firstSteps.isSortedDescendant(matrix4));
        int[][] matrix5 = {{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {12, 5, 4, 3}, {34, 12, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6}};
        assertTrue(firstSteps.isSortedDescendant(matrix5));
    }
```

My code is

```
public boolean isSortedDescendant(int[][] matrix) {
        if ((matrix.length == 0) || (matrix.length == 1)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length - 1; j++) {
                    if (matrix[i][j] <= matrix[i + 1][j + 1]) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The code is returning wrong answers.

Comment: Can you clear sorting of matrix with an example ?

Comment: Can you give an example of what input is producing the wrong output? Also, that code is liable to produce an exception because you can index out of the array.

Comment: First test  int[][] matrix1 = {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 4, 3}, {8, 7, 6}};
        assertTrue(firstSteps.isSortedDescendant(matrix1)); Returns false but shoud return true. Becouse elemnts of matrix is sorted from highest value to lowest.

Comment: Can you describe what exactly sorted means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your test cases, I think you want to check if each row is sorted or not.

Here are the changes

1. This `i < matrix.length - 1` to `i < matrix.length` to check all the rows.
2. This `matrix[i][j] <= matrix[i + 1][j + 1]` to `matrix[i][j] <= matrix[i][j + 1]` to compare the elements of the same row.
3. This `j < matrix.length - 1` to `j < matrix[i].length - 1`. It will ensure the logic works even if the matrix is not a square matrix

```java
public boolean isSortedDescendant(int[][] matrix) {
    if ((matrix.length == 0) || (matrix.length == 1)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length - 1; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] <= matrix[i][j + 1]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

There is a simpler way to write the above logic

```java
public boolean isSortedDescendant(int matrix[][]) {
    for(int[] row: matrix)
        for(int i = 1; i < row.length; i++)
            if(row[i] >= row[i-1])
                return false;
                
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your simple version is working, while version above dont compile and return error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4

Comment: I have updated the code by changing `matrix[0].length - 1` to `matrix[i].length - 1`, now it works fine.